# Problem with virtual desktop in wine

Tags: 13.10, wine, resolution, games

I got an issue with the virtual desktop for my wine installation.
When is set the resolution for it window size for the width never becomes bigger than 800 px. The actual size of the desktop seems to be bigger though since games identify it correctly resulting in warped images when they are run in full screen.
Changing the resolution in a game (been using Sky drift) to a different resolution and back again sets the window to a correct size.
I have tried different versions of wine, at the moment 1.7.8.
My ubuntu version is 13.10

Edit:
Important details I didn't have time to file.
I'm using PlayOnLinux 4.2.1-1 and configure the resolution of the virtual desktop using the "configure wine" tool.

Comment: Are you using the 'configure wine' tool? You should be able to alter the size of the virtual desktop. Click graphics, then 'emulate a virtual desktop'.

Comment: Yes I do and unfortunately it doesn't work. I added some more info above.